# Eloquent; getting rows not in other table

Tags: eloquent

I'm trying to get a list of records from a table, where the PK is not in a composite table. If you see consider below table, I'm trying to get all `candidates` that are not in a `pool`, so in this case I should get only `Eric`.

```
+-------------+     +-------------+
| candidates  |     | pools       |
+-------------+     +-------------+
| id | name   |     | id | name   |
+----+--------|     +----+--------|
|  1 | John   |     |  1 | Pool A |
|  2 | Richard|     |  2 | Pool B |
|  3 | Eric   |     |  3 | Pool C | 
+----+--------+     +----+--------+

+--------------------------+
| candidate_pools          |
+--------------------------+
| pool_id | candidate_id   |
+---------+----------------|
|  1      | 1              |
|  1      | 2              |
|  3      | 2              |
|  2      | 1              |
+---------+----------------+
```

I've found this answer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-records-collection-if-not-exists-in-another-table

```
$crashedCarIds = CrashedCar::pluck('car_id')->all();
$cars = Car::whereNotIn('id', $crashedCarIds)->select(...)->get();
```

Which should work, however it seems extremely inefficient in our fairly big and rapidly growing database, on a page that is accessed often by a lot of people.

In normal MySQL you would do something like this:

```
WHERE candidates.id NOT IN
( SELECT candidate_id
           FROM candidate_pools
      LEFT JOIN pools
             ON candidate_pools.pool_id = pool.id
)
```

Note: The tables are just a simple illustration, but the actual database set-up and queries are a lot bigger.

Comment: Why don't you try by setting an eloquent relationship with your model? Have you already did it? For example, Pool model hasMany candidates and Candidate model belongsTo Pool.

Comment: @RutvijKothari Thanks but that is not related to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using scope, like this:

```
public function scopeNotInPool($query) {

    $query->whereNotIn('candidate_id', function ($query) {
        $query->select('candidate_id')
              ->from('candidate_pool')
              ->join('pool', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('pool.id', '=', 'candidate_pool.pool_id');
                }
            )

        ;
    });

    return $query;

}
```

Then call it like:

```
$candidates = Models\Candidate::notInPool()->get();
```